# NSUserDefaults dont persist even when using synchronize

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsuserdefaults, synchronize

My `NSUserDefaults` work fine while the app is running or minimized. But if I kill the app and restart it, the object returned is `null`. Code:

```
colorDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[colorDefault setObject:myColor2 forKey:@"fieldKey"];
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myColor2, @"fieldKey", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
//[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

[colorDefault synchronize];
```

I call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` in my `applicationDidEnterBackground` and in the `applicationWillTerminate`, with no success. I *NSLogged* both of those methods, and when I kill the app, I notice only the `DidEnterBackground` is being called..

Thanks for ANY help!

Comment: Show the code where a nil object is being returned, including where it is called from. Also, where in your app is the above code? What do you think registerDefaults: should be doing?

Comment: What is the myColor2 variable type ? Have you read the reference here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html for the details of how registerDefaults is working ?

Comment: Somehow, I didn't find this older post, but i have an IDENTICAL scenario: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349648/nsuserdefaults-wont-save-permanantly)

Except that I call my default in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear (viewDidLoad is called every time the app starts so it would obviously need to be there too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmmm... I think your code should be simpler.

This is what I do to write NSUserDefault and to retrieve it:

```
// write
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"aString" forKey:@"aKey"];

// read
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"aKey"];
```

setObject is not the only option: setBool, setFloat, setInteger and on the other side boolForKey, floatForKey, integerForKey are good as well.

Do not forget to set `Settings.bundle` and `aKey` in your project:

```
<dict>
<key>Key</key>
<string>aKey</string>
<key>DefaultValue</key>
<false/>
</dict>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Sorry guys. All the things you mentioned were valid, but it ended up being this:

    `String == @"Blue" //instead of
    String isEqualToString:@"Blue"`

Weird how it works fine before you close the app. But afterwords, it changes it's mind. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah... I see. Always use isEqualToString when comparing strings: it seems that == operator compares object addresses instead of their contents!!! (you are welcome ^_^)

Comment: I recommend you to read the documentation, registerDefaults: is used for a different thing than setValue:forKey: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults: